# Importing database (created using datatool) to datatooltk

Tags: datatool, database

I have created database (very large database)  of questions using datatool as

```
\DTLnewdb{finitemath}
\long\def\newproblem#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
  \DTLnewrow{finitemath}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{seq}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{yr}{#2}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{sub}{#3}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{top}{#4}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{mar}{#5}%
\DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{qus}{#6}%
\DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{url}{#7}%
\DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{exp}{#8}%
\DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{ans}{#9}%
}

\newproblem{1}{2018}{DM}{comb}{1}{
\textbf{Which one of the following\begin{lstlisting}
 is a closed form expression for the generating function of\end{lstlisting}
the sequence $\{a_n\}$, where $a_n = 2n +3 \text{ for all } n=0, 1, 2, \dots$?}\\
$($A$)$ $\frac{3}{(1-x)^2}$\\
$($B$)$ $\frac{3x}{(1-x)^2}$\\
$($C$)$ $\frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}$\\
$($D$)$ $\frac{3-x}{(1-x)^2}$\\
}{\url{http://gatefreaks.com/index.php?qa=9036&qa_1=dm-gate-2015-3-1}}{.}{Ans:d}
```

Database has 9 different columns.I have 10 such database files .I use master file to combine all these database and when i compile it  output a sorted pdf file (acc to any of the field). But compilation takes hours. 
Is there any way to make it efficient.

I read somewhere that it can be done using datatooltk.But i am not able to figure out, how to import my database to datatooltk? 
Is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you be able to switch to LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have at least version 1.8 (2018-01-26) of [`datatooltk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk). You also need at least Java 7. ([Java 8](https://java.com/en/download/) is the current version.)

To install `datatooltk`, download [`datatooltk-installer.jar`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/datatooltk/datatooltk-installer.jar) from CTAN and run it. If your operating system recognises the `.jar` extension as a Java application, you should be able to double-click or use "Open with..." otherwise you can install from the command line:

```
java -jar datatooltk-installer.jar
```

There's a GUI mode and a batch mode. The installer should put a link to the GUI version in the applications menu, although this may vary according to the operating system. In GUI mode use **File -> Open** and select the `.tex` file containing your problem definitions. With a bit of luck it should be able to parse your definition of `\newproblem`. If not try replacing

```
\long\def\newproblem#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
```

with

```
\newcommand{\newproblem}[9]{%
```

As long as there isn't anything too complicated in your `.tex` file, it should be able to create the database. (If it's a big file it may take a while to parse.) You can then save it to a `.dbtex` file using **Save as...**. Then you can load the `.dbtex` file in your document using `\input` or `\DTLloaddbtex`.

Alternatively, from the command line:

```
datatooltk --in inputfile.tex --output outputfile.dbtex
```

If you need to sort the data, it's more efficient to perform it in the same step. For example:

```
datatooltk --in inputfile.tex --sort yr --output outputfile.dbtex
```

When you open a `.tex` file that isn't in the `.dbtex` format, you'll get a message:

```
Quick load failed (Premature end of file. Failed to find '\newtoks\csname').
Trying again with TeX Parser Library.
```

This just means that `datatooltk` is switching to using the TeX parser library to interpret the file contents, which is slower than its default method of loading a `.dbtex` file.

Related: [`datatool` performance](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/datatool-performance.shtml).

Comment: Thank you so much, Nicola Talbot. I  loaded 2 database files 11g.dbtex and 2005it.dbtex  shown below

\documentclass[a4paper]{article} \input{11g.dbtex} \input{2005it.dbtex} \begin{document}  \DTLforeach[\DTLisclosedbetween{\seq}{1}{100}]% {finitemath} {\DTLifstringeq{\sub}{DM}{{ \item \qus  }{}}

 \end{document}

But on compilation, it is showing result corresponding to 2005it.dbtex(last database loaded). I tried many combinations but every time it is showing result corresponding to the last database loaded. Is it possible to get a result as the combination of all database files