# Merging different dbtex database files

Tags: macros, datatool, database

I want to merge 2 database files in one file . I tried loading files 11g.dbtex and 2005it.dbtex as shown below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{datatool}
\newcommand{\altura}{.45cm}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{longdata}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.markings,arrows}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newif\ifsolns \solnsfalse

\input{11g.dbtex} \input{2005it.dbtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\DTLforeach[\DTLisclosedbetween{\seq}{1}{100}]% {finitemath}%
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}%
{\DTLifstringeq{\sub}{DM}{ {\DTLifstringeq{\top}{logic}{ \item \qus }{}} }{}}
\end{enumerate} \end{document}
```

But after compilation, it is showing result corresponding to 2005it.dbtex(last database loaded). I tried many combinations but every time it is showing result corresponding to the last database loaded. Is it possible to get a result as the combination of all database files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `.dbtex` contains a single database with a unique label. From [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417043), I'm basing this on file `11g.tex`:

```
\DTLnewdb{finitemath}
\long\def\newproblem#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
 \DTLnewrow{finitemath}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{seq}{#1}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{yr}{#2}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{sub}{#3}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{top}{#4}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{mar}{#5}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{qus}{#6}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{url}{#7}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{exp}{#8}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{ans}{#9}%
}

\newproblem{1}{2018}{DM}{comb}{1}{question 1}{url 1}{exp 1}{ans 1}
% lots more \newproblem commands
```

But what about file `2005it.tex`? You haven't provided enough information. Does it start in the same way? Like this:

```
\DTLnewdb{finitemath}
\long\def\newproblem#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
 \DTLnewrow{finitemath}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{seq}{#1}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{yr}{#2}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{sub}{#3}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{top}{#4}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{mar}{#5}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{qus}{#6}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{url}{#7}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{exp}{#8}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{finitemath}{ans}{#9}%
}

\newproblem{2}{2018}{DM}{comb}{1}{question 2}{url 2}{exp 2}{ans 2}
```

If this is the case then you can't input both `11g.tex` and `2005it.tex` as `\DTLnewdb{finitemath}` is in conflict. So I'm assuming this isn't the case. Perhaps `2005it.tex` is more like this:

```
\DTLnewdb{somethingelse}
\long\def\newproblem#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
 \DTLnewrow{somethingelse}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{seq}{#1}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{yr}{#2}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{sub}{#3}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{top}{#4}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{mar}{#5}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{qus}{#6}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{url}{#7}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{exp}{#8}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{somethingelse}{ans}{#9}%
}

\newproblem{2}{2018}{DM}{comb}{1}{question 2}{url 2}{exp 2}{ans 2}
```

Or do you have a single definition of `\newproblem` and a single instance of `\DTLnewdb` in one `.tex` file that's used across the document?

The second case seems the most likely. In which case, I'm guessing you obtained the `.dbtex` files by first changing `\long\def\newproblem#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9` in the `.tex` files to `\providecommand{\newproblem}[9]` and then used:

```
datatooltk --in 11g.tex --output 11g.dbtex 
datatooltk --in 2005it.tex --output 2005it.dbtex
```

This creates `11g.dbtex` that contains the definition of the database extracted from `11g.tex`, which is identified by the label `finitemath`, and `2005it.dbtex` that contains the definition of the database extracted from `2005it.tex`, which is identified by whatever label was used in that file (`somethingelse`).

This means that in the document, if you want to reference the data in `11g.dbtex` then you need to identify it by `finitemath` and if you want to reference the data in `2005it.dbtex` then you need to identify it by whatever the associated label is (`somethingelse`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\input{11g.dbtex}
\input{2005it.dbtex}

\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{finitemath}% data from 11g.dbtex
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}
{%
 %... whatever
}

\DTLforeach{somethingelse}% data from 2005it.dbtex
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}
{%
 %... whatever
}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to keep track of the label you can use `\DTLloaddbtex` instead, which allows you to assign a command in which to store the label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddbtex{\dataI}{11g.dbtex}
\DTLloaddbtex{\dataII}{2005it.dbtex}

\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{\dataI}% data from 11g.dbtex
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}
{%
 %... whatever
}

\DTLforeach{\dataII}% data from 2005it.dbtex
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}
{%
 %... whatever
}

\end{document}
```

You can iterate over the second database and append it to the first, but that rather defeats the purpose of using `datatooltk` to improve the document build.

A simpler solution is to move `\DTLnewdb` and the definition of `\newproblem` to a new file, called, say `problems.tex`:

```
\newcommand{\databaselabel}{finitemath}

\DTLnewdb{\databaselabel}
\providecommand{\newproblem}[9]{%
 \DTLnewrow{\databaselabel}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{seq}{#1}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{yr}{#2}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{sub}{#3}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{top}{#4}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{mar}{#5}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{qus}{#6}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{url}{#7}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{exp}{#8}%
 \DTLnewdbentry{\databaselabel}{ans}{#9}%
}

\input{11g.tex}
\input{2005it.tex}
```

And remove those lines from `11g.tex` and `2005it.tex`.

Here's the modified `11g.tex`:

```
\newproblem{1}{2018}{DM}{comb}{1}{question 1}{url 1}{exp 1}{ans 1}
% lots more \newproblem
```

and here's the modified `2005it.tex`:

```
\newproblem{2}{2018}{DM}{comb}{1}{question 2}{url 2}{exp 2}{ans 2}
% lots more \newproblem
```

Now you just need to change the first line of `problems.tex` to change the database label, and add or remove `\input` lines to merge extra files (assuming they all simply contain multiple instances of `\newproblem`). This means that only one call of `datatooltk` is required:

```
datatooltk --in problems.tex --output problems.dbtex
```

This creates a database containing all the problems. Since you're using `datatooltk` it's more efficient to apply the filtering at this point instead of using the optional argument of `\DTLforeach`:

```
datatooltk --in problems.tex --output problems.dbtex --filter-and --filter seq ge 1 --filter seq le 100 --filter sub eq DM --filter top eq logic
```

You only need to run `datatooltk` whenever the data or the condition changes. Now when `problems.dbtex` is input in the document, it only contains the filtered selection. This makes the loop much faster (even more so if you use the starred read-only version of `\DTLforeach`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddbtex{\problemdb}{problems.dbtex}

\begin{document}
\DTLforeach*{\problemdb}% 
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}
{%
 %... whatever
}

\end{document}
```

If you have another loop with a different condition, you just need another `datatooltk` call. For example:

```
datatooltk --name problems1 --in problems.tex --output problems1.dbtex --filter-and --filter seq ge 1 --filter seq le 100 --filter sub eq DM --filter top eq logic
datatooltk --name problems2 --in problems.tex --output problems2.dbtex --filter-and --filter seq ge 1 --filter seq le 100 --filter sub eq DM --filter top eq algebra
```

The `--name` switch assigns a new label, which can be used to avoid label conflict.

The modified document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddbtex{\problemIdb}{problems1.dbtex}
\DTLloaddbtex{\problemIIdb}{problems2.dbtex}

\begin{document}
\DTLforeach*{\problemIdb}% 
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}
{%
 %... whatever
}

\DTLforeach*{\problemIIdb}% 
{\seq=seq,\yr=yr,\sub=sub, \top=top, \mar=mar,\qus=qus, \ans=ans}
{%
 %... whatever
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nicola Talbot. It was really heapfull. Is it possible to export dbtex database to Mysql database?

Comment: @GarveshGv No, I'm sorry. `datatooltk` can only import from MySQL not export.